# Making VectorSpace.Scalar instance of Eq

Tags: haskell, type-families

Note: I may not need to add Scalar to Eq, although it should solve the problem if I could figure out how to do just that.

So I'm trying to add some functionality to the [ForceLayout](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/force-layout/0.1.0.1/doc/html/Physics-ForceLayout.html) module. Adding mass to Particles like so:

```
data Particle v = Particle { 
                         _pos   :: Point v
                       , _vel   :: v
                       , _force :: v
                       , _mass :: Scalar v
                       }
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

But [Scalar](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.7.3/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html#t%3aScalar) is not in Eq or Show! So this wont compile. Mass should be a scalar "compatible" with the other vectors though. How can I reconcile this? I don't understand type families sufficiently to analyse this situation. I've tried but they are mighty hard to grasp. Not sure if adding Scalar to Eq is necessary or possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show the mass field, the show instance is going to have to look like

```
instance (Show v, Show (Point v), Show (Scalar v)) => Show (Particle v) where
```

Arguably, the fact that GHC doesn't work this out is a bug, or at least a missing feature. Luckily, with some extension heavy lifting, we can give it the context ourselves:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, TypeFamilies,
    FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
{- ... -}

deriving instance (Show v, Show (Point v), Show (Scalar v)) => Show (Particle v)
```

This is a "standalone deriving declaration" as described in [the GHC user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving), and its purpose here is basically so that we can specify a context that GHC wouldn't normally be able to work out.

That ought to do the trick. I'm a little worried about the UndecidableInstances, since it *does* seem like it ought to be possible to define instances of `Point` and `Scalar` such that this instance is circular, but despite my best efforts I haven't been able to make the typechecker loop, so it's probably fine.

Comment: Also note that you can always just write your own instance declarations by hand. All deriving does is automate some boilerplate for you...

Comment: (Sorry, I rewrote this comment. Previous was confused.) Thanks! I can't seem to make the standalone deriving to work. However, writing it manually, adding Eq v to the conditions, seem to work (so far)!

Comment: What's wrong with the standalone deriving? It worked for me on a similar example

Comment: Hmm. I must have done something wrong. It even works with fclabels now. I had to write the stand-alone deriving clauses like this though (not a negative turn, just a correction): "deriving instance (Show v, Show (Point v), Show (Scalar v)) => Show (Particle v)". Analogically for Eq. Seems to work great!